# Legends are not matching with columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, legend

I am trying to plot a timeseries graph of excel data by using python. My data looks like this:

```
         date   x  y  z  Status Charge
0  1995-02-01   1  0  0     NaN     a1
1  1995-02-02   2  1  1     NaN     a1
2  1995-02-03   3  0  0     NaN     a2
3  1995-02-04   4  0  0     NaN     a3
4  1995-02-05   5  0  0     NaN     a4
5  1995-02-06   6  0  0     NaN     a5
6  1995-02-07   7  0  0     NaN     a6
7  1995-02-08   8  0  0     NaN     a7
8  1995-02-09   9  0  0     NaN     a8
9  1995-02-10  10  0  0     NaN     a9
10 1995-02-11  11  0  0     NaN    a10
11 1995-02-12  12  0  0     NaN    a11
12 1995-02-13  13  0  0     NaN    a12>
```

First, I want to split data according to column `x`. Second, I want to plot the `z` column by the charge column. I tried to use following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i, group in df.groupby('x'):
    plt.figure()
    grouped=group.groupby(df['Charge'])
    grouped.plot(x='date', y='z', title=str(i),marker='o',linestyle='', legend=True)
```

But when I used that, legends are not matching with the groups in the 'charge' column. Does anyone have an idea about how I can fix that?

Comment: You should edit your question to provide your example as text, not image (just copy-paste the output of `df.head(10)`). You should also properly indent your code after the `for` loop.

Comment: Please fix your indentation and show us the output

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need another `for` loop to plot your second `GroupBy` object.

Comment: I guessed by I couldn't make it. @IanS